Flight left while checked in passenger queued for boarding
A most unusual situation happened to a friend: they were travelling Ryanair, checked in fine and in good time, with checked in luggage, queuing for boarding. Suddenly the airline just announced "actually that's it folks, the plane is full, if you didn't make it, tough, come see us for a replacement flight", with people still in the queue.
My friend went over to Ryanair desk, who did put her on another flight, flying to a totally different part of the destination country - a good few hrs travel. They did have the option, at that point, to fly to the original destination, however ultimate arrival time would be much later than flying to a replacement destination+transfer/connecting flight. Initially, my friend hoped to fly Ryanair from that town to her ultimate destination, but as the replacement flight itself was delayed (joint effort by Ryanair and slow luggage handling at the replacement destination) they missed that, as well as any other viable transport links (trains etc). They have some friends in the replacement destination, so stayed the night and travelled onwards safely the next day.
However, it seems like Ryanair would be liable for some compensation. The most glaring fault would appear to be not letting a checked in passenger on board, with no compensation, and leading to a nearly 24h delay of the total journey. Even had they switched to a flight to the original destination, the total delay would be around 12hrs, assuming everything else goes to plan. Further, even though my friend stayed with friends, they are out of pocket for the train ticket they bought the next day.
Do you have any advice on what specific claims can be made, and in particular how to make them against the giant of customer service that is Ryanair?

What were the origin and destination and what was the operating airline (shown on the ticket)? Most like EC261 applies, see https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm what was the reason for refusing boarding?

@jcaron THe flight was overbooked

@Crazydre that would seem surprising for Ryanair, wouldn’t it? Also it would happen at check-in and not boarding, given seats are assigned at check-in at the latest. One possible option could be that there was a malfunction in the aircraft which prevented them from operating at full capacity (which would be liable for compensation) but there could be other cases which do not.

@jcaron Though they claim not to overbook, they occasionally do, but try to hide as much as possible the rights for passengers. The claim form doesn't even list a "denied boarding" option, only "cancellation" and "delay", hence it has to be sent via email

@Crazydre and jcaron The other thing that's odd is to suddenly announce that in the queue for boarding. As far as I can tell, even Ryanair assigns a seat at check-in nowadays, even specifically randomizing seats to nudge groups into paying extra. So even if there was some overbooking or aircraft switch, they would know before and look for volunteers a bit earlier than that.

@Relaxed I've had Ryanair give me seat 0 for a STN-EDI flight, with the actual seat assigned at the gate

@Crazydre So what's the procedure? The seats get assigned at the gate while boarding is ongoing? The overbooked passengers get seat 0 and they keep assigning them seats until they run out? Everybody who hasn't paid for a seat gets one at the gate? What happens to the people who did pay extra for a specific seat? I still have trouble understanding how they make sure the “right” people are denied boarding and they don't end up with a bunch of double-booked seats on the plane with the procedure described by the OP.

@Relaxed Yes, the seat is assigned during boarding. Regarding the rest I don't know sadly. Similar case: was denied boarding twice in a row on EJ MLA-LGW, and after the second re-routing they blocked onliine check-in and had me go to the desk to get my boarding pass (which again the contractors refused until I had EJs passport/visa team intervene). It then said seat "SAG" on my boarding pass, I was escorted to the gate by and agent and then got seat 1A at the gate

If you abstract away from the procedural unusualness, this is just the (fairly common) case of passengers being denied boarding because of overbooking. All airlines do it, most are just a bit more graceful about the situation.

If there was no public transport, they would be perfectly entitled to get a taxi to their final destination and have Ryanair pay for it, even if it cost hundreds of euros.

@Crazymoomin Correct; for instance when I was denied boarding CHQ-GLA, and EJ re-booked me to HER-LGW-EDI, they told me to make my own way CHQ-HER. Since the bus wouldn't have got me to HER in time, I thus paid EUR 195 for a taxi. Zero issues whatsoever.

Is it possible that the person was flying standby? Being "checked in" doesn't necessarily mean you actually have a seat on the plane yet. The situation described in the question would be completely normal and typically not subject to any additional compensation in the case of a standby passenger. Standby passengers can still check in at the normal time, but usually don't receive a seat assignment until at the gate shortly before departure.

Ryanair. Enough said! :-p

The most surprising thing about this story to me is that there was checked luggage. The phrasing makes it sound like the plane just took off, with the friend’s luggage still on the plane, which seems very unlike any airline. Generally speaking, if a passenger doesn’t board a flight, nor does their luggage, for security reasons. @Bennet, did your friend actually get their luggage back, or did it go with the plane to the original destination?

"they were travelling Ryanair ..." unfortunately its' a case of "You can stop there ..."    :/  What a bummer.

@JanusBahsJacquet No, the EU has always allowed unaccompanied baggage to fly if the bag is separated from the passenger due to reasons outside their control. Additionally, if the bag has been screened with advanced systems (e.g. CT scanners) or hand searched, the bag can fly unaccompanied, see EU EC 2320/2002 5.2.2. In the US, advanced scanning became mandatory, so unaccompanied bags aren't offloaded for security purposes.

@user71659 I see. I’ve been in situations where a passenger failed to turn up after checking in and the flight ended up being delayed because they had to get the no-show’s luggage back out of the hold – but presumably they then consider that not to be outside the passenger’s control (potentially, at least), increasing the risk.

The passenger is entitled to:

EUR 250, 400 or 600 in denied boarding compensation depending on the original route
reimbursement for costs of travelling to the final destination
reimbursement for meals if they still have receipts.
possibly reimbursement for the missed "connecting" flight because it was caused by a delay to the first one.

The passenger should email the claim to eu261@ryanair.com with the booking reference in the title, outline the claim in listed form, provide the BIC/SWIFT and IBAN, and attach all receipts of expenses. They should ask Ryanair for a response within 14 days.

Quite helpful. Additional provision and citation of applicable treaties/conventions/policies form which these rights are claimed to have arisen would be most useful. Provision of relevant EU complaint procedure would also be helpful.

@CobyViner There is no “EU complaint procedure”. Complaint is made to the airline, and then if the response was not satisfactory to the agency that the relevant country has desgnated to handle EC261 complaints.

The overwhelming problem is that Ryanair simply won't pay.  They will just ignore it, stall, "lose correspondence" and so on until a couple of years have gone by.  It's tough when you are in a "you simply won't beat them" situation.

@Fattie Not really! You give them 14 days, then send a reminder for them to either reply within a few more days or you're taking it to court. They can only stall you if you let them

Fair enough.  "or you're taking it to court" - but how, at what cost, can you sue for costs as well ?

@Fattie You can sue for the claim fee and any trial fees, yes

Fair.  Suing someone is quite a risk of 5 - 50 thousand pounds.  I feel it's realistic to point out that Ryanair never or rarely pays.  But yes your info on how to claim is the immediate and perfect info OP needs !

@Fattie At least in UK small claims court it is NOT routine for the loser to pay the winner's costs (other than the claim and trial fees). I've claimed many times from Ryanair and only once did I have to go to court (at which point they settled hiding behind their third-party solicitor firm)
